# Override default notification led color

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, led

I am developing an application to blink the notification led for the events like inbox messages and missed calls based on the user choice in different colors.

When an inbox message is received then I will start blinking the LED (Using Notification.ledARGB).

But the problem is the LED is blinking with the default color(white - which is the default led color for messages) but not the color set by me/user. 
How to avoid or override blinking the default message app color and show my LED color?

I wanted to provide more details regarding my question to get the better answer.
What I am doing is when i get a incoming message i am getting broadcast receiver and catching the action and showing my notification with some color. The notification is showing in status bar but the color is coming white color (may it is message app default color).

While by researching a lot I came to know that whichever app is raised the notification first that notification led color will blink till we cancel the notification by swiping from the notification bar or by clicking. If we rise our notification with our custom color it will not blink till that previous notification is canceled.So what I want to do is I want to stop blinking of the default color and start blinking the color set by me.

I am using LG Nexus 4 with Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

You must override all the Notification defaults by setting:

```
notif.defaults = 0;
```

Here's a snippet of code:

```
private void RedFlashLight()
{
    NotificationManager nm = ( NotificationManager ) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    Notification notif = new Notification();
    notif.defaults = 0;
    notif.ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notif.ledOnMS = 100; 
    notif.ledOffMS = 100; 
    nm.notify(LED_NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [setLights](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setLights%28int,%20int,%20int%29) method for notification builder.

```
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
notificationBuilder.setLights(Color.CYAN, 5000, 5000);  //you can give your choice's color here.
```

Make sure to override defaults using this flag:

```
Notification notification; 
notification.defaults = 0;
```

Hope this helps.